# min-width, max-width, width. Nothing work in IE8 on body tag

Tags: html, css

This is my web page which doesn't work in IE8 but works in FF 3.6.4 and Opera 9.63 :-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">


            body{
                max-width:10002px;
                min-width:3072px;
                width:10002px;
                margin:0px auto;
                background:#293231;
                height:100%;
                padding:0px;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body >


    </body>
</html>
```

No scrollbar appears at the bottom of the page in ***IE8***

Comment: What `doctype` are you using for your HTML?

Comment: There is no doctype. This is just a test page that i created in notepad and saved it as .html

Comment: Then _add_ a proper doctype. IE8 uses the doctype for rendering, and without a doctype it will probably go into quirks mode.

Comment: Ok! Let me add. Will tell you the results asap.

Comment: I added this doctype :- 

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

But now even in Mozilla scrollbar disappeared :(.

Comment: Have you looked at the _strict_ xhtml one?

Comment: Yep! i used this too :- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

But results are the same.

Comment: Looks like if you want a scrollbar at the bottom for all browsers, you will need the content area to be wider than the client display width, just setting it in CSS is not enough for IE8 or FF.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I pasted few images that is wider than my screen. The scrollbar showed up nicely :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add a doctype declaration to your page - this will make sure most browsers behave as closely as possible the same way. At least it will eliminate one class of possible issues.

Most of the time, when it comes to scrollbars, they will appear only when *content* is wider/higher then the client display area, whatever the CSS rules are.

Answer (score 5):

There is no point in setting `max-width` and `min-width` if you are going to set a `width` value that will cause them to be ignored. In your example `min-width` will never be used as you've already set `width` to a greater value. Likewise, `max-width` is unnecessary here because `width` has been set to the same value.

This would be a more appropriate use of the three:

```
div.yourdiv {
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This `div` will be 50% of the width of the element containing it, but will not exceed 300px in width or fall below 100px in width.